# Loading an uncompressed DDS to GL texture

Tags: opengl, colors, textures, texture2d, dds-format

I've [this DDS](http://www.riemers.net/Downloads/resources/Series4/grass.dds) file. I wrote a simple DDS reader to read a DDS header and print its details based on the MSDN specification. It says that the it's an RGB DDS with 32 bytes per pixel bit depth and the alpha is ignored i.e. pixel format is X8R8G8B8 (or A8R8G8B8). To verify this, I also opened this file in a hex editor which shows the first (i.e. from the data start) 4 bytes as `BB GG RR 00` (replace them with the first pixel's right hex colour values). [I read](http://lists.openscenegraph.org/pipermail/osg-users-openscenegraph.org/2009-December/036897.html) that OpenGL's texture copy functions act on bytes (atleast conceptually) and thus from its viewpoint, this data is B8G8R8A8. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong here.

Now to `glTexImage2D` *internal format* I pass `RGBA8` and to *external format* and *type* I pass `BGRA` and `UNSIGNED_BYTE`. This leads to a blue tint in the rendered output. In my fragment shader, just to verify, I did a swizzle to swap `R` and `B` and it renders correctly.

I reverted the shader code and then replaced the *type* from `UNSIGNED_BYTE` with `UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` (based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626437/183120)) and it still renders the blue tint. Now changing the *external format* to `RGBA` and with either *type* (`UNSIGNED_BYTE` or `UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`) it renders fine!

- Since OpenGL doesn't support ARGB, giving BGRA is understandable. But how come RGBA is working correctly here? This seems wrong.
- Why does the *type* have no effect on the ordering of the channels?
- Does the GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT have a bearing in this? I left it as the default (4). If I read the manual right, this should have no effect on how the client memory is read.

**Details**

- OpenGL version 3.3
- Intel HD Graphics that supports upto OpenGL 4.0
- Used [GLI](http://gli.g-truc.net/) to load the DDS file and get the data pointer

Comment: Can I take a look to your reader?

Comment: Back when I asked this, I'd written something throw-away. Thanks to you for asking, I ended up writing something anew: [shared here](https://gist.github.com/legends2k/97584e4c576d7b5e0dcf)! As the answer says, the aforementioned issue was due to a bug in GLI which was fixed recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answers myself! Posting it here so that it may help someone in future.

> Since OpenGL doesn't support ARGB, giving BGRA is understandable. But how come RGBA is working correctly here? This seems wrong.

By inspecting the memory pointed to by `void* data` that GLI returns when a pointer to the image's binary data is asked for, it can be seen that GLI had already reordered the bytes when transferring data from the file to client memory. The memeory window shows, from lower to higher address, data in the form `RR GG BB AA`. This explains why passing `GL_RGBA` works. However, the wrong on GLI's part is that when external format is queried for it returns `GL_BGRA` instead of `GL_RGBA`. [A bug](https://github.com/g-truc/gli/issues/43) to address this has been raised.

> Why does the *type* have no effect on the ordering of the channels?

No, it has an effect. The machine that I'm trying this experiment on is an Intel x86_64 little endian machine. [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Endian_issues) clearly states that the client pixel data is always in client byte ordering. Now when `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` is passed, the underlying base type (not the component type) is an `unsigned int` for both; thus reading an `int` from `data`, on a little-endian machine would mean, the variable in register would end up with the bytes swapped i.e. `RR GG BB AA` in the RAM would reach the VRAM as`AA BB GG RR`; when addressed by a texture of type RGBA (`RR GG BB AA`), reading `AA` would actually give `RR`. To correct it, the OpenGL implementation swaps the bytes to neutralise the endianness of the machine, in the case of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` *type*. While for `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` we explicitly instruct OpenGL to swap the byte order and thus it renders correctly. However, if the *type* is passed as `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` then the rendering is screwed up, since we instruct OpenGL to copy the bytes as it was read on the machine.

> Does the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` have a bearing in this? I left it as the default (4). If I read the manual right, this should have no effect on how the client memory is read.

It does have a bearing on the unpacking of texture data from client memory to server memory. However, that's to account for the padding bytes present in an image's rows to compute the stride (pitch) correctly. But to this issue specifically it doesn't have a bearing since it's pitch flag is 0 i.e. there're no padding bits in the DDS file in question.

Related material: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_type

Comment: This answer is hopefully correct, but I'm not 100% sure of it since I'd made some assumptions in my deduction. If it's wrong some of the masters of [tag:opengl] may please get me out of my ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, the DDS file format can have padding for alignment. In the D3D world, that sort of thing is referred to as "pitch". You may want to read up on the section on `dwPitchOrLinearSize` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943991(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've updated the answer; I read the documentation hastily, my bad. Hope the rest of it is correct.