# OpenGL transparency doing weird things

Tags: opengl, transparency

I am trying to render a texture with an alpha channel in it.

This is what I used for texture loading:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

I enabled `GL_BLEND` just before I render the texture: `glEnable(GL_BLEND);`

I also did this at the beginning of the code(the initialization): `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

This is the result(It should be a transparent texture of a first person hand):
[image]

But when I load my texture like this(no alpha channel):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Does anyone know what can cause this, or do I have to give more code?
Sorry for bad English, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My texture loading code:

```
GLuint Texture::loadTexture(const char * imagepath) {

    printf("Reading image %s\n", imagepath);

    // Data read from the header of the BMP file
    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned int dataPos;
    unsigned int imageSize;
    unsigned int width, height;
    // Actual RGB data
    unsigned char * data;

    // Open the file
    FILE * file = fopen(imagepath, "rb");
    if (!file) { printf("%s could not be opened. \n", imagepath); getchar(); exit(0); }

    // Read the header, i.e. the 54 first bytes

    // If less than 54 bytes are read, problem
    if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // A BMP files always begins with "BM"
    if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // Make sure this is a 24bpp file
    if (*(int*)&(header[0x1E]) != 0) { printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");}
    if (*(int*)&(header[0x1C]) != 24) { printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");}

    // Read the information about the image
    dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
    width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
    height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

    // Some BMP files are misformatted, guess missing information
    if (imageSize == 0)    imageSize = width*height * 3; // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component
    if (dataPos == 0)      dataPos = 54; // The BMP header is done that way

                                         // Create a buffer
    data = new unsigned char[imageSize];

    // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
    fread(data, 1, imageSize, file);

    // Everything is in memory now, the file wan be closed
    fclose(file);

    // Create one OpenGL texture
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    if (imagepath == "hand.bmp") {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }else {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    delete[] data;
    return textureID;
}
```

As you can see its not my own written code, Ive got it from opengl-tutorial.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first comment stated:

> The repeating, offset pattern looks like the data is treated as having a larger offset, when in reality it has smaller (or opposite).

And that was before I actually noticed what you did. Yes, this is precisely that. You can't treat 4-bytes-per-pixel data as 3-bytes-per-pixel data. The alpha channel gets interpreted as colour and that's why it all offsets this way.

If you want to disregard the alpha channel, you need to strip it off when loading so that it ends up having 3 bytes for each pixel value in the OpenGL texture memory. (That's what **@RetoKoradi**'s answer is proposing, namely creating an RGB texture from RGBA data).

---

If it isn't actually supposed to look so blue-ish, maybe it's not actually in BGR layout?

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                                                          ^
                                                          \--- change to GL_RGBA as well
```

My wild guess is that human skin would have more red than blue light reflected by it.

Comment: But my texture is transparent(At least I think, it is a bitmap image)

Comment: @OpenGLManiac There's no such thing as a "transparent texture". There are 3-channel textures and 4-channel textures. Yours, if loaded as RGBA (4 channels - R,G,B and A) looks correctly.

Comment: Okay I made the GL_BGRA, GL_RGBA as well but now the white part of the texture is light blue and the hand is red :/

Comment: @OpenGLManiac That was just a guess, you are the one who knows how your memory is laid out. Open up your debugger, look into pixel data and look at the value for the first pixel (which I assume should be transparent) - if the 4th byte is 0, it might be RGBA or BGRA. If the first one is 0, it might be something weird like ARGB or ABGR. Point being, it all has to be matched and taught to OpenGL correctly, because all it sees are bytes.

Comment: @OpenGLManiac And by the way, if it turns out that alpha actually *is* the first (0-th) channel, [you don't need to reverse it by hand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18626437/752976).

Comment: Uuhm, I don't know if this is correct but this is what the debugger says about the data: '\0'

Comment: @OpenGLManiac oh, nvm about the comment I deleted, you should probably follow Barteks advice and try `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`

Comment: When I put GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV instead of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, the white background of the image is now lightblue and the hand is now red/pink.

Comment: I updated my post with the whole code for texture loading, can you see if there is something wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you misunderstood how the arguments of `glTexImage2D()` work:

- The 3rd argument (*internalformat*) defines what format you want to use for the data stored in the texture.
- The 7th and 8th argument (*format* and *type*) define the format of the data you pass into the call as the last argument.

Based on this, if the format of the data you're passing as the last argument is BGRA, and you want to create an RGB texture from it, the correct call is:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Note that the 7th argument is now `GL_BGRA`, matching your input data, while the 3rd argument is `GL_RGB`, specifying that you want to use an RGB texture.

Comment: The texture is still yellow and blue(first picture I posted)

Comment: It would be. Since the pixels land at correct places already, the only thing this achieves is disregarding the alpha channel and putting 1 for it every time a pixel from this texture is rendered, which probably wasn't the goal.

Comment: @OpenGLManiac The way I read your question, it sounded to me like the first image was what you wanted, and you didn't understand why the second one was messed up. If the color of the first one is already wrong, it could be RGBA instead of BGRA.

Comment: I updated my post with the whole code for texture loading, can you see if there is something wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Seams you chose worng texture pixel alignment. To specify the right one try to experiment with values (1, 2, 4) of `glPixelStorei` with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`.

Specification:

```
void glPixelStorei( GLenum pname,  
  GLint param);
```

**`pname`** Specifies the symbolic name of the parameter to be set. One value affects the packing of pixel data into memory: `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`. The other affects the unpacking of pixel data from memory: `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`.

**`param`** Specifies the value that pname is set to.

`glPixelStorei` sets pixel storage modes that affect the operation of subsequent `glReadPixels` as well as the unpacking of texture patterns (see `glTexImage2D` and g`lTexSubImage2D`).

pname is a symbolic constant indicating the parameter to be set, and param is the new value. One storage parameter affects how pixel data is returned to client memory:

**`GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`**
Specifies the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row in memory. The allowable values are 1 (byte-alignment), 2 (rows aligned to even-numbered bytes), 4 (word-alignment), and 8 (rows start on double-word boundaries).

The other storage parameter affects how pixel data is read from client memory:

**`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`**
Specifies the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row in memory. The allowable values are 1 (byte-alignment), 2 (rows aligned to even-numbered bytes), 4 (word-alignment), and 8 (rows start on double-word boundaries).

The following table gives the type, initial value, and range of valid values for each storage parameter that can be set with `glPixelStorei`.

**BMP format do not support transparency at least most common 3 version (only work `GL_BGR` mode and its masked modifications). USE PNG, DDS, TIFF, TGA(simplest) instead.**

Secondly your total image data size computation formula is wrong

```
imageSize = width*height * 3; // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component
```

Right formula is:

```
imageSize = 4 * ((width * bitsPerPel + 31) / 32) * height;
```

where `bitsPerPel` is current picture bits per pixel (8, 16 or 24).

Here is the code of function wich used to load simple TGA files with transparency support:

```
// Define targa header.
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
    {
    GLbyte  identsize;              // Size of ID field that follows header (0)
    GLbyte  colorMapType;           // 0 = None, 1 = paletted
    GLbyte  imageType;              // 0 = none, 1 = indexed, 2 = rgb, 3 = grey, +8=rle
    unsigned short  colorMapStart;          // First colour map entry
    unsigned short  colorMapLength;         // Number of colors
    unsigned char   colorMapBits;   // bits per palette entry
    unsigned short  xstart;                 // image x origin
    unsigned short  ystart;                 // image y origin
    unsigned short  width;                  // width in pixels
    unsigned short  height;                 // height in pixels
    GLbyte  bits;                   // bits per pixel (8 16, 24, 32)
    GLbyte  descriptor;             // image descriptor
    } TGAHEADER;
#pragma pack(8)

GLbyte *gltLoadTGA(const char *szFileName, GLint *iWidth, GLint *iHeight, GLint *iComponents, GLenum *eFormat)
    {
    FILE *pFile;            // File pointer
    TGAHEADER tgaHeader;        // TGA file header
    unsigned long lImageSize;       // Size in bytes of image
    short sDepth;           // Pixel depth;
    GLbyte  *pBits = NULL;          // Pointer to bits

    // Default/Failed values
    *iWidth = 0;
    *iHeight = 0;
    *eFormat = GL_BGR_EXT;
    *iComponents = GL_RGB8;

    // Attempt to open the fil
    pFile = fopen(szFileName, "rb");
    if(pFile == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Read in header (binary)
    fread(&tgaHeader, 18/* sizeof(TGAHEADER)*/, 1, pFile);

    // Do byte swap for big vs little endian
#ifdef __APPLE__
    BYTE_SWAP(tgaHeader.colorMapStart);
    BYTE_SWAP(tgaHeader.colorMapLength);
    BYTE_SWAP(tgaHeader.xstart);
    BYTE_SWAP(tgaHeader.ystart);
    BYTE_SWAP(tgaHeader.width);
    BYTE_SWAP(tgaHeader.height);
#endif


    // Get width, height, and depth of texture
    *iWidth = tgaHeader.width;
    *iHeight = tgaHeader.height;
    sDepth = tgaHeader.bits / 8;

    // Put some validity checks here. Very simply, I only understand
    // or care about 8, 24, or 32 bit targa's.
    if(tgaHeader.bits != 8 && tgaHeader.bits != 24 && tgaHeader.bits != 32)
        return NULL;

    // Calculate size of image buffer
    lImageSize = tgaHeader.width * tgaHeader.height * sDepth;

    // Allocate memory and check for success
    pBits = new GLbyte[lImageSize];
    if(pBits == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Read in the bits
    // Check for read error. This should catch RLE or other 
    // weird formats that I don't want to recognize
    if(fread(pBits, lImageSize, 1, pFile) != 1)
        {
        free(pBits);
        return NULL;
        }

    // Set OpenGL format expected
    switch(sDepth)
        {
        case 3:     // Most likely case
            *eFormat = GL_BGR_EXT;
            *iComponents = GL_RGB8;
            break;
        case 4:
            *eFormat = GL_BGRA_EXT;
            *iComponents = GL_RGBA8;
            break;
        case 1:
            *eFormat = GL_LUMINANCE;
            *iComponents = GL_LUMINANCE8;
            break;
        };


    // Done with File
    fclose(pFile);

    // Return pointer to image data
    return pBits;
    }
```

`iWidth`, `iHeight` return texture dimensions, `eFormat` i `iCompoments` external and internal image formats. than actual function return value is pointer to texture data.

So your function must look like:

```
GLuint Texture::loadTexture(const char * imagepath) {

    printf("Reading image %s\n", imagepath);

    // Data read from the header of the BMP file
    int width, height;
    int component;
    GLenum eFormat;

    // Actual RGB data
    char * data = LoadTGA(imagepath, &width, &height, &component, &eFormat);

    // Create one OpenGL texture
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    if (!strcmp(imagepath,"hand.tga")) { // important because we comparing strings not pointers
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, component, width, height, 0, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }else {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, component, width, height, 0, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    delete[] data;
    return textureID;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand much of it, but can you give the code that maybe can solve the problem? By the way, my image i am using is a bitmap image. Is this a probm? Cause I heard that bitmaps cannot handle an alpha channel.

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`, or `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2)`, `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4)`, or `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 8)` before your `glTexImage` call.

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: As example bmp 24 bit format is aligned to 4 bytes. Simple byte data is aligned to 1 byte. Choose align values considering image format you read.

Comment: Unfortunately none of them worked. It is still the same as the first picture I posted.

Comment: I updated my post with the whole code for texture loading, can you see if there is something wrong with it?

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: BMP format do not support transparency at all. USE PNG, DDS, TIFF, TGA(simplest) instead.

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: I have upated my answer.

Comment: But how do I use this with openGL because I need a GLuint for the openGL texture.

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: It return texture data read from file. You can use this data to call `glTexImage`.

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: You can create TGA files using photoshop info TGA is common texture format for GTA San Adnreas.

Comment: I hope that was a joke XD

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: I do not understand, what is the catch?

Comment: I actually prefer playing TGA San Andreas

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: GTA or TGA?

Comment: Okay I have a question: What do I fill in the arguments of your loading function?

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: Only input parameter is `szFileName` others a outputs (can be any values (prefer set it to 0))

Comment: I already tried setting them to 0 but then i get this error: "iWidth was nullptr'. And I guess the same for the other values I gave as arguments.

Comment: I load like this: gltLoadTGA(path,0,0,0,0);

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: Its output parameters so they must be initialized by extermat variables pointers as you can see from the declaration, one minute i'll post call pattern.

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: Now must be OK, I also found mistake in string comparison `if (imagepath == "hand.bmp")`.

Comment: Okay the function worked, and now I see the texture. But it's transparency I gave is not there. I checked if my image has alpha channel and it did. Do you have any idea why it's still not working?

Comment: Plus its not cubemap as i see `    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
` so the value of target must be GL_TEXTURE_2D not GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP. And you can leave behing thrid conponent of wrapping glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: You must also specify texture environment or work with shaders.

Comment: This is my fragment shader:

#version 330 core

in vec2 uv;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D txtSampler;

void main(){
 color = texture(txtSampler, uv).rgb;
}

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: Its hard to say considering there are many approaches to receive transparent textures (multipass techniques, defered shading, multitexture blending, texture environment usage). Its all depend what did you use to present the thansparent hand. It seams the you must use not only 1 shader.

Comment: I fixed it by doing this in the frag shader:  if(color.r == 1 && color.g == 1 && color.b == 1){
  discard;
 }

So the white color wont be displayed. Thanks for your help, I learned a lot about textures alpha channels and tga images :)

Comment: @OpenGL Maniac: Glad can help you!) Good luck!)